# Horizontal scroll bar in IE7

Tags: html, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-7

If you look at http://wilwaldon.com/JLS10/dine.html in IE7 (the devil) you will see a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of your browser. I've tried to hide the overflow of pretty much every `<div>` and I've taken out every element in the layout one by one to see what could be causing this issue. I just can't seem to wrap my brain around it right now. Firebug isn't helping either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by `position: absolute` on `#summer`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I swear I took that out at one point to debug the page, but apparently not. Keen eye ;)